Proving that solutions to equation in quadratic number fields are conjugates.
Say we have the equation $x^4 + y^4 = 8$ and we want to find the solutions to this in quadratic number fields.
By intuition, it would seem that solutions are conjugates. Namely, $x = a + b\sqrt{d}$ and $y = a - b\sqrt{d}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$.
The way I tried to attempt this is to first parametrize $(x^2, y^2)$, which can be done as $$(x^2, y^2) = \left (\frac{t^2 + 2t - 1}{t^2 + 1} , \frac{t^2 -2t - 1}{t^2  +1} \right)$$
I have already found all solutions for $t$ rational, so now I am interested in when $t$ is irrational, and it would make it easier if $x, y$ are conjugates as described above.
If $t = \sqrt{d}$ for a squarefree integer $d$ this is trivial, but how can we prove this for $t = m + n\sqrt{d}$?
Thanks in advance

I tried plugging in $t = m + n \sqrt{d}$ but it just resulted in a lengthy expression that seemed to go nowhere.

If you plug in $ x, y = m \pm n \sqrt{d} $, you will obtain a quadratic equation of $m^2$ (or $n^2$). Then you get a necessary condition that the discriminant has to be a perfect square for this to hold. More can probably be said if you then require the solution to be perfect square too.

I understand for $x, y$ = $m +\pm n\sqrt{d}$, but is it possible for the solutions to not be conjugates?
